# Return the file extension from filename using string index in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, text, indexing

I am having a bit of trouble putting this logic on paper:

The string I would like to parse: `"Jan - 2012 Presentation v1.3.ppt.pdf - 500KB"`
This string can vary but the structure is always "NAME+EXT+FILESIZE"

I want to return the extension. However for obvious reasons I cannot just `split(".")`
So I came up with something else:

```
stringy = "Jan - 2012 Presentation v1.3.ppt.pdf - 500KB"
ext = [".pdf",".jpg",".ppt",".txt",".doc"]

for i in ext:
    indx = stringy.find(i)
    ...
```

I got stuck where I need to figure out how to tell Python to take the extension starting with the biggest index yielded. Should be something like `whatiwant = stringy[indx:4]`, but I can't figure out how to tell it to only take the largest index... The largest index will obviously mean the last extension in the string, which is the one I want to get. In this particular example, I don't care about "ppt", but rather the "pdf".

Can this perhaps be done in a more pythonic way? Or at least more efficiently?

Comment: Is the dash("-") in all occurrences of the string?

Comment: For this specific problem, there is also `string`'s `rfind`.

Comment: the dash is always at the end to separate the filesize part of the string. yes.

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't this a valid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [44]: stringy[stringy.rfind('.'):stringy.rfind('.')+4]
Out[44]: '.pdf'
```

Comment: looks very promising. I will run this through a few variations of strings. 
So rfind will find anything starting from the right side of the string  and takes the usual [x:y] stuff to denote what to cut?

Comment: marking this as the answer for two reasons:
1 - Very straightforward and uncomplicated
2 - First answer that worked and worked well on a array of filenames all with varying structure.

Avasal, are you aware of anything that can potentially "break" this method of extracting the extension?

Comment: @Capt.Morgan: if it is so "straightforward and uncomplicated" can't you yourself tell what will break this method?

Comment: It was a question for the poster, not the arsey kid who has nothing better to do in SO, other than leaving unhelpful and unproductive comments. If you have nothing of use to contribute, please do not post, full stop. [EDIT] it's a little immature to be so butthurt because I did not pick your answer, don't you think?

Comment: @Capt.Morgan: Immature is to post pathetic question asking people to do work for you. Immature is to not understand one's own limitation. Immature is to be rude to people who help you.

Comment: 1 - There are no "pathetic" questions, if you could see past your "internet rage" you would see that.
2 - Afaik this is a website where people help people. The concept of "help" is relative, and if from time to time someone needs a bit of hand holding, who are you to judge?
3 - You haven't helped me at all, in fact - you wasted my time with your comment. You have been a hindrance; Accept that. Move on with life.

Comment: @Capt.Morgan I think  SilentGhost's answer was the best solution for this problem, this solution can easily break for a extension whose length is greater than or equal to 4 characters, say `.torrent`,`.docx`

Answer (score 1):

using `regex`:

```
>>> strs="Jan - 2012 Presentation v1.3.ppt.pdf - 500KB"

>>> re.findall(r"(\.\w+)",strs)[-1]
'.pdf'
```

**or:**

```
>>> re.findall(r".*(\.\w+)",strs)
['.pdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> stringy = "Jan - 2012 Presentation v1.3.ppt.pdf - 500KB"
>>> extension = stringy.split(".")[-1].split("-")[0].strip()
>>> extension
'pdf'
```

Comment: This will get the file size as well